# Definition associated with being attached to your own decisions, even when they are proven bad

Tags: terminology

There is a psychological effect I read about that I'm trying to remember the name of regarding people being overly attached to their decisions as being the best, because they made that decision, even if they are proven by facts to be a bad decision. Can anyone remind of the name of this psychological effect?

Example:

Person 1: "I bought the [insert product name] and it is better than all other options"

Person 2: "That product has actually been proven to be the worst option"

Person 2: (Provides factual proof)

Person 1: "No, [insert product name] is the best option there is.

Comment: Confirmation bias: See [Denial of evidence and reason](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/13173/7001), [Do people have a tendency to stick to one opinion after they formed it?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/117/7001), [What is the psychological term for disregarding correct but unwanted information?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/12416/7001), [Is there a specific term for false justifications?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/12419/7001).

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg this is the correct answer and what i was looking for, add it as an answer and i will mark it as such